# Enumerate all modules in a .pm file, and get an reference of them all

Tags: perl, oop, package

I'm trying to avoid `Module::Pluggable` and make thing easier.

Here's what I do, I have a set of modules stored in `modules/`, all packages defined inside share the same method names:

```
# in XX.pm
package MyClass::XX;
sub new {}    
sub method_1 {}    
sub method_2 {}

# in YY.pm
package MyClass::YY;
sub new {}    
sub method_1 {}    
sub method_2 {}
```

(But note that there might be more than one module defined in a single .pm file)

Now I want to get all objects blessed to these modules, e.g `[ XX->new, YY->new]`

Is that possible?

Comment: `XXX->new`, etc. typically returns a reference that is blessed into package `XXX`, but is not a reference to package `XXX`, whatever that is. Perhaps you could clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry, it's not any clearer. What is a reference to a module? It looks like you might be interested in objects blessed into each package.

Comment: @mob objects then, I'm really confused by these terms sorry ;-(

Comment: @mob question updated

Comment: "I'm trying to avoid Module::Pluggable and make thing easier." - The second half of your sentence seems to contradict the first :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to loop through this `modules/` directory you say you have, and gather a list of files in it. (Use `opendir` or better yet, [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path%3a%3aTiny) to gather the list of files.) Then:

```
my @classes = map {
   (my $class = $_) =~ s{/}{::}g;
   $class =~ s{\.pm\z}{};
   $class;
} @files;
```

In the above I'm assuming a fairly standard filename-to-classname mapping. Feel free to tweak it if it doesn't fit your situation.

Once you have a list of classes, you can get back a list of objects pretty easily:

```
my @objects = map $_->new, @classes;
```

Personally I'd use [Module::Pluggable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module%3a%3aPluggable) though. Don't be afraid of the deprecation warnings. The module is not deprecated. What the warnings mean is that the copy of Module::Pluggable that comes bundled with the Perl interpreter is being phased out. Instead you should install a copy from the CPAN.